# pysftp: how to get remote folder size

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

How to get size of a remote folder when using pysftp?

The object return by stat seems doesn't looks right, my code:

```
fdStat = sftpClient.stat(remotePath);
print(fdStat.st_size);
```

output:

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 0        99           4096 21 Sep 11:13 ?
4096
```

=> the folder `remotePath` is huge and it's size much larger than 4096.

Answer (score 1):

The `.stat` method returns the same information as the *nix `ls` command. The size here represents the size of data, the directory itself (= metadata about contained files) occupies on the disk. It's not the size of the contained files.

There's no direct way to obtain a total size of a files in a directory using a single call in pysftp or SFTP protocol in general.

All you can do it to list the directory (recursively if needed) and sum the sizes of individual files.

Answer (score 0):

i work around by calling execute(), then process the return value, for linux server:

`sftpClient.execute("du --apparent-size --block-size=1 " + remotePath)`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'SFTPClient' object has no attribute 'execute'`